# Why the PDO statement error comes in this code?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, fetch, associative-array

I have the following code, I am unable to figure out why the PDO statement error occurs, here is my code

```
try {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=imdb","username","pwd");
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $first_name=$db->quote($first_name);
        $last_name=$db->quote($last_name);
        $row_id=$db->query("SELECT id FROM actors WHERE last_name=$last_name AND first_name LIKE ${first_name} ORDER BY film_count DESC LIMIT 1");
        if ($row_id->rowCount() > 0) {
            $idrow=$row_id->fetch_assoc();
                print_r($idrow);
            return $row_id;
        }
        else {
            return Null;
        }
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
    ?>
        <p>Sorry, a database error occurred. Please try again later.</p> 
        <p>(Error details: <?= $ex->getMessage() ?>)</p>
    <?php
        return NULL;
    }
```

I get this error when I run

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetch_assoc()

Any help?

Comment: please consult http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because just like the error says. `fetch_assoc()` isn't defined.

You want

```
$row_id->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

`fetch()` is the correct method name and you pass it one of the [PDO Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php) to determine what type of variable to get back.

Comment: Thanks. this helped. however, I came across the I used above in manual. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php.

Comment: Thanks. this helped. however, I came across the I used above in manual. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php. In the above code, return $row_id does not return anything, is this because it is consumed during the fetch?

Comment: Yes. If you return `$row_id`, it's now just an empty statement handle. If there was another row it would return another object you could fetch from. You probably are wanting to return `$idrow`.